# SQLite database on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, fmdb

Hello i'm using FMDB to use SQLite database. And i have next code:

```
FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:@"stories_db.sqlite"];
[db open];
FMResultSet *resultsFavorite = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * from favorites"];
```

But there is error shown on [db open];

2013-10-23 11:08:22.951 Pasakas[1013:a0b] error opening!: 14

[image]

Maybe i should change the path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give **path** of database  not name of database,

try with

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"stories_db.sqlite"];

FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:path];
[db open];
FMResultSet *resultsFavorite = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * from favorites"];
```

Comment: +1 But before doing this... you have to copy your local database file to document directory.. great..

Comment: 2013-10-23 11:20:24.211 Pasakas[1093:a0b] DB Error: 1 "no such table: favorites"
2013-10-23 11:20:24.212 Pasakas[1093:a0b] DB Query: SELECT * from favorites
2013-10-23 11:20:24.213 Pasakas[1093:a0b] DB Path: /Users/artjomsfomenko/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/645A59FD-1667-4A4B-8B24-EF87C2A3D271/Documents/stories_db.sqlite

Comment: CREATE TABLE "offline" ("_id" TEXT PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "story_name" TEXT NOT NULL , "video_path" TEXT, "image_path" TEXT)